# redirecting to homepage after user submits a blog post?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

I'm very new to using Django and coding in general. So I have figured out how to make the form submit to my database but now when it submits, it just brings you to the blank blog_post view and I'm not understanding how to redirect correctly.

here is the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import post
from django.views import generic, View
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import PostForm

# Views for post list


class postslist(generic.ListView):
    model = post
    queryset = post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'home.html'
    paginate_by = 4

# view for individual post


class postdetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = post
    template_name = "post.html"


def blog_post(request):

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
        return redirect("blog:success")

    context = {'form': form,
               }

    return render(request, "create_post.html", context)


def success(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("home.html")
```

urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
    # home
    path('', views.postslist.as_view(), name='home'), 
    # add post
    path('blog_post/', views.blog_post, name='blog_post'),
    # success for blog post
    path('success/', views.success, name='success'),
    # posts
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.postdetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

I have tried a few variations of httpresponseredirect and redirect but I just cant wrap my head around it, nor can I find it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect to the home in `success` with:

```
from django.utils import redirect


def success(request):
    return redirect('blog:home')
```

You should however *only* redirect in case the form was successful, so:

```
def blog_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog:home')  # 🖘 only if the form is valid
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_post.html', context)
```

The above is what a `CreateView` does however. You thus can implement this with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'create_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: I also had the idea of redirecting only when the form is valid but couldn't maintain indentation(writing from phone), after looking at your answer I checked mine then I came to know +1

Comment: this is very informative, so i would in a sense be better off replacing the view i have built with this? do i just change the view name in the URLs.py then?

Comment: @jakemcp97 The path should be `path('blog_post/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='blog_post')` additionally I'd say to change name of `postdetail` and `postslist` view to `PostDetailView` and `PostListView` respectively, as name of the class based views are generally written in PascalCase and that too by using model name as prefix, and actual view name (of Django) as suffix.

Comment: Switching to class based solved the issue once i removed some conflicts in the admin.py! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to redirect in `home.html` which is rendered by `postslist` view so the view should be like this:

```py
def blog_post(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
       form=PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect("blog:home")
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    context = {'form': form,
               }

    return render(request, "create_post.html", context)
```

Also need to specify `app_name='blog'` in urls.py so:

```py
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *

app_name='blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # home
    path('', views.postslist.as_view(), name='home'), 
    # add post
    path('blog_post/', views.blog_post, name='blog_post'),
    # posts
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.postdetail.as_view(), name='post_detail')
]
```

Remove that `success` view no need for it.